# How to use r purrr:map to create multiple of the same object (such as data frame)

Tags: r, purrr

I want to know to what extent it is possible to use purrr's mapping functions to create objects in general, though at the moment and with the example below I'm looking at data frames.

```
A<-seq(1:5)
B<-seq(6:10)
C<-c("x","y","x","y","x")
dat<data.frame(A,B,C)
cols<-names(dat)

create_df<-function(x) {
    x<- dat[x]
    return(x)
}
A<-create_df("A")
```

This will create a data frame called A with column A from dat. I want to create data frames A/B/C, each with one column. I have tried different ways of specifying the .f argument as well as different map functions (map, map2, map_dfc, etc.). My original best guess:

```
map(.x=cols,~create_df(.x))
```

Clarification: I am asking for help because all of the specifications of map that I have tried have given an error.

Code that worked:

```
map(names(dat), ~assign(.x, dat[.x], envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

This creates A/B/C as data frames and prints to the console (which I don't need but does not bother me for now).

Comment: How do you want to store those data frames? With this `library(tidyverse);

map(names(dat), ~dat[.])` you'll get a list of dataframes.

Comment: How does your `map(.x=cols...)` not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @CPak I updated-- I'm getting an error when I run the map function.

Comment: @AntoniosK I was able to produce this output previously. I want the data frames to exist as objects in the environment after running map()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `purrr` package, I think your custom function is not necessary.
The function includes a reference to the data, which is not optimal (especially if it doesn't exist in the environment).

to return as a list of single column dataframes:

```
cols<-names(dat)
map(cols, ~dat[.x])
```

or alternatively: `map(names(dat), ~dat[.x])`

returns:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 1
      A
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 1
      B
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  C    
  <chr>
1 x    
2 y    
3 x    
4 y    
5 x
```

If you want to stick with `tidyverse` principles, you can store them within a dataframe as a list-column.

```
dfs <-
  data_frame(column = cols) %>% 
    mutate(data = map(cols, ~dat[.x]))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  column data            
  <chr>  <list>          
1 A      <tibble [5 x 1]>
2 B      <tibble [5 x 1]>
3 C      <tibble [5 x 1]>
```

You can pull out individual data as needed:

```
B <- dfs$data[[2]]  

# A tibble: 5 x 1
      B
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

Along the lines of your original suggestion, here's an alternative function that uses `purrr:map` within it. I'm not sure how good of an idea this is, but maybe it has a use:

```
create_objects_from_df <- function(dat) {
  map(names(dat), ~assign(.x, dat[.x], envir = .GlobalEnv))
  }
create_objects_from_df(dat)
```

This creates the objects in your global environment, as individual objects with the column names.

Comment: When I run map(cols, ~dat[.x]), I get an error: Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, .x) : undefined columns selected

Comment: make sure that the `cols` variable is still defined as in the original post. I've also added an alternative in the edit where you don't have to define a new variable.

Comment: I did have an issue with cols but fixing it only prints the output to the console (same with your alternate suggestion); it does not create the data frames. if i create a list object from it lst2<-map(cols,_dat[.x]) and then compare to @akrun code I get to very similar lists, except that the elements in lst2 do not have a name (@akrun code names the elements A, B, C). using list2env does not work when I try to combine with map in this way.

Comment: yes- unless you name the objects individually it won't create an object.

Comment: if you really want all those objects- see the function version at the end of my answer. With really large dataframes I'm not sure this would be good. That function will create the objects in your global environment

Comment: That worked, without the wrapper function! Final code in my updated question. I hadn't seen assign() before. This does result in the DF's being printed to console and creates the objects, but the printing to console is something I can deal with later/ignore. I'm coming from more of a SAS background where the assign() and envir= were more implicit. I'm needing to learn these tricks to have greater control over the objects I create.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split` from `base R` to get a `list` of one column `data.frame`s

```
lst <- split.default(dat, names(dat))
```

It is better to keep it in a `list`, but if the intention is to have multiple objects in the global environment

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you, as this works. However I do have a preference for using purrr:map-- as I'm getting deeper into R I am trying to focus on finding solutions within the tidyverse first as that is the direction of my learning.

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett No problem.  Makes sense